# How to pass array to another page by using anchor in php

Tags: php

I have to pass an array value from one php page to another php page using `<a href>` ... here is my coding

`$cluster` is an array

```
echo "<td><a href=myebon.php&cluster[]=".$cluster.">Click here to OFF</a></td>";
```

in *myebon.php*

```
$n=count($_GET[cluster]);
for($i=0;$i<=$n;$i++)
{
    echo $cluster[$i]=$_GET['cluster'][$i];
}
```

The value is not accessible in the second page, it's displaying as array but not the values. I have tried serialization concept too ...

Comment: This is not an answer. [Laxus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14980062/165154) already provided a proper one. However, your code is really sloppy. The query string behind `myebon.php` should start with a question-mark `?`, not with an ampersand `&`. Ideally you'd wrap the full link in quotes as well, i.e. `href="myebon.php?etc="`. Lastly when accessing a string key of an array the key should be a string, i.e. `$_GET['cluster']`, not `$_GET[cluster]`. In the latter one PHP will think you meant to use a CONSTANT by the name of `cluster`, not a string literal `'cluster'`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning all

Comment: sorry i have added ? after href but still its not working... i have tried all  the answer which is previously posted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is clear example code

first.php

```
<?php
$Mixed = array("1","2","3");
$Text = json_encode($Mixed);
$RequestText = urlencode($Text);
?>
<a href="second.php?cluster=<?php echo $RequestText; ?>">Click</a>
```

second.php

```
<?php
$Text = urldecode($_REQUEST['cluster']);
$Mixed = json_decode($Text);
print_r( $Mixed);
?>
```

I have checked, and it is working fine.

Comment: hey value is passing in url .. but i cant get the exact values of array in next page .. i m trying really hard but cant get the answer in second page .. i tried ur program too its not working

Answer (score 5):

Use [http_build_query](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
$data = array('foo', 'bar', 'lol');

echo '<a href="myebon.php?' . http_build_query(array('cluster' => $data)) . '">link</a>';
```

Output

```
<a href="myebon.php?cluster%5B0%5D=foo&cluster%5B1%5D=bar&cluster%5B2%5D=lol">link</a>
```

It can be retrieved with `$_GET['cluster']`, e.g:

```
foreach ($_GET['cluster'] as $val) { 
    // my work here, example:
    echo $val , "\n";
}
```

Comment: ya the values are displaying as array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "73" [1]=> string(2) "71" [2]=> string(2) "73" } ... but how can i use the values

Comment: TO access the value in second page i used the cluster value without var_dump($_GET['cluster']);

Comment: in `myebon.php` use `foreach ($_GET['cluster'] as $val) { // my work here, example: echo $val , "\n"; }` to iterate it

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = serialize($array);
```

Then pass the string, in other page use

```
$array = unserialize($string);
```

Try this :

```
echo "<td><a href=myebon.php&cluster=".serialize($cluster).">Click here to OFF</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you pass the array like below:

```
//QueryString Variable
$qs = '';
foreach($cluster as $cl)
    $qs .= "&cluster[] =".$cl;
```

and then use this variable as below in link building:

```
echo "<td><a href=myebon.php?a=1".$qs.">Click here to OFF</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON_ENCODE with URLENCODE

First

```
$Text = json_encode(array('foo', 'bar', 'lol'));
$RequestText =urlencode($Text);
```

Then

```
echo "<td><a href=myebon.php&cluster=".$RequestText.">Click here to OFF</a></td>";
```

Second: myebon.php

```
$Text = urldecode($_REQUEST['cluster']);
$Mixed = json_decode($Text);
```

This will work fine.

Comment: i can get value as [\"73\",\"71\",\"73\"] ... in myebon.php ... how can i use the values alone

Comment: $Text = urldecode($_REQUEST['cluster']);
$Mixed = json_decode($Text); print_f($Mixed);  // $Mixed is your actual array

Comment: hey check out i have posted my coding

Answer (score 0):

coding of my first page

```
$Text = json_encode($cluster);
$RequestText =urlencode($Text);
echo '<table>';
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
{
 for($x=0;$x<=$c1;$x++)
 {
     if($cluster[$i]==$ebclus[$x])
     {    

         echo "<tr><td>".$cname[$i]."</td><td>".$cluster[$i]."</td><td>".$statusid[$x]."</td>";
         if($statusid[$x]==ON)
         {
             echo "<td><a href=myebon.php?&dept=".$dept."&branch=".$branch."&end=".$c1."&start=".$i."&cluster=".$RequestText.">Click here to OFF</a></td>";
         }  
         elseif($statusid[$x]==OFF)
         {
             echo "<td><a href=myebon.php?&dept=".$dept."&branch=".$branch."&end=".$c1."&start=".$i."&cluster=".$RequestText.">Click here to ON</a></td>";
         }
     }
 }   
}
```

myebon.php

```
$dept=$_GET[dept];

$branch=$_GET[branch];
$end=$_GET[end];
$start=$_GET[start];
$Text = urldecode($_REQUEST['cluster']);
$Mixed = json_decode($Text);
echo $Mixed;
for($i=0;$i<=$end;$i++)
{
    echo $Mixed[$i];
}
```

The answer is displaying as [\"73\",\"71\",\"73\"]