# Pass specific sub array to another page php

Tags: php

So I have a list of items that are being displayed like this :

```
<tbody>
<?php
$count = 1;
foreach ($parser['LXEPricerGrid']['PassingLoans']['PassingLoan'] as $key) {
?>
   <tr>
   <?php
   echo '<td>' . $count . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $key['LerProductName'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $key['Rate'] . '%</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $key['APR'] . '%</td>';
   echo '<td style="text-align: right">$' . $key['MonthlyPayment'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td><a href="#">Apply</a></td>';
   echo '<td><a href="#">Details</a></td>';
   ?>
   </tr>
   <?php
   $count++;

}
?>
</tbody>
```

Now all is well and good but what i want is that when i click on the Details link it should open another page and show all the values of the specific item against which i clicked details. I m not very good with PHP in React you could pass down as props or do a variety of other stuff but i don't know how to do this with php. any help appreciated.
The array looks like :

```
 [PassingLoan] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [LerId] => 599
                                    [LerName] => United Wholesale Mortgage
                                    [LerProductId] => 91821
                                    [LerProductName] => Conquest FannieMae Elite 30 Year Fixed
                                    [LoanCategoryClass] => F360
                                    [LoanCategoryAmortization] => 30
                                    [LoanCategoryTerm] => 30
                                    [TargetMargin] => 100.899
                                    [LOComp] => 0.899
                                    [MaxEarningInPoints] => 9999999
                                    [MinEarningInPoints] => 0
                                    [PricesheetCompType] => 0
                                    [LerProductARMIndex] => 11
                                    [IndexName] => N/A
                                    [IndexValue] => 0
                                    [IndexDate] => 04/06/2008
                                    [IndexTime] => 02:48:02 PM
                                    [LerProductARMIndexMargin] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [LerProductARMLifeCap] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [LerProductARMFirstAdj] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [LerProductARMFirstAdjCap] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [LerProductARMPerAdj] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [LerProductARMPerAdjCap] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [LerProductProgram] => 0
                                    [LerProductFannieFreddie_SW] => 0
                                    [HomePath] => No
                                    [DURefi_HARP] => No
                                    [InterestOnly] => No
                                    [OpenAccess_HARP] => No
                                    [LerProductAllowPropertyLocationStandard] => 1
                                    [LerProductAllowPropertyLocationRural] => 1
                                    [LerProductLerPaidMI] => 0
                                    [SubPrime] => 0
                                    [Rate] =>   2.875
                                    [Points] => 101.307
                                    [Base] => 101.307
                                    [RateBase] => 101.307
                                    [Credit] => 1632
                                    [APR] => 2.900
                                    [MonthlyPayment] => 1659.57
                                    [MI] => 0.00
                                    [RateUp1] =>   2.998
                                    [PointsUp1] => 101.793
                                    [BaseUp1] => 101.307
                                    [RateBaseUp1] => 101.793
                                    [CreditUp1] => 3576
                                    [APRUp1] => 2.998
                                    [MonthlyPaymentUp1] => 1685.98
                                    [MIUp1] => 0.00
                                    [RateUp2] => 0
                                    [PointsUp2] => 0.000
                                    [BaseUp2] => 0.000
                                    [RateBaseUp2] => 0.000
                                    [CreditUp2] => 0
                                    [APRUp2] => 0
                                    [MonthlyPaymentUp2] => 0
                                    [MIUp2] => 0
                                    [RateUp3] => 0
                                    [PointsUp3] => 0.000
                                    [RateBaseUp3] => 0.000
                                    [BaseUp3] => 0.000
                                    [CreditUp3] => 0
                                    [APRUp3] => 0
                                    [MonthlyPaymentUp3] => 0
                                    [MIUp3] => 0
                                    [RateUp4] => 0
                                    [PointsUp4] => 0.000
                                    [RateBaseUp4] => 0.000
                                    [BaseUp4] => 0.000
                                    [CreditUp4] => 0
                                    [APRUp4] => 0
                                    [MonthlyPaymentUp4] => 0
                                    [MIUp4] => 0
                                    [RateUp5] => 0
                                    [PointsUp5] => 0.000
                                    [RateBaseUp5] => 0.000
                                    [BaseUp5] => 0.000
                                    [CreditUp5] => 0
                                    [APRUp5] => 0
                                    [MonthlyPaymentUp5] => 0
                                    [MIUp5] => 0
                                    [RateDown1] =>   2.750
                                    [PointsDown1] => 100.684
                                    [BaseDown1] => 101.307
                                    [RateBaseDown1] => 100.684
                                    [CreditDown1] => -860
                                    [APRDown1] => 2.824
                                    [MonthlyPaymentDown1] => 1632.96
                                    [MIDown1] => 0.00
                                    [RateDown2] =>   2.625
                                    [PointsDown2] => 99.922
                                    [BaseDown2] => 101.307
                                    [RateBaseDown2] => 99.922
                                    [CreditDown2] => -3908
                                    [APRDown2] => 2.758
                                    [MonthlyPaymentDown2] => 1606.60
                                    [MIDown2] => 0.00
                                    [RateDown3] =>   2.500
                                    [PointsDown3] => 99.083
                                    [BaseDown3] => 101.307
                                    [RateBaseDown3] => 99.083
                                    [CreditDown3] => -7264
                                    [APRDown3] => 2.698
                                    [MonthlyPaymentDown3] => 1580.48
                                    [MIDown3] => 0.00
                                    [RateDown4] => 0
                                    [PointsDown4] => 0.000
                                    [BaseDown4] => 0.000
                                    [RateBaseDown4] => 0.000
                                    [CreditDown4] => 0
                                    [APRDown4] => 0
                                    [MonthlyPaymentDown4] => 0
                                    [MIDown4] => 0
                                    [RateDown5] => 0
                                    [PointsDown5] => 0.000
                                    [BaseDown5] => 101.307
                                    [RateBaseDown5] => 0.000
                                    [CreditDown5] => 1632
                                    [APRDown5] => 0
                                    [MonthlyPaymentDown5] => 0
                                    [MIDown5] => 0
                                    [TotalAdjustments] => 0
                                    [BuydownPoints] => 0
                                    [DownPayment] => 200000
                                    [TotalFees] => 2940
                                    [APRFees] => 2940
                                    [POCFees] => 0
                                    [LerFees] => 2940
                                    [OriginationFees] => 0
                                    [ApplicationFee] => 150
                                    [ProcessingFee] => 1055
                                    [TaxFee] => 0
                                    [UnderWritingFee] => 0
                                    [DocumentFee] => 0
                                    [AdministrativeFee] => 450
                                    [CourierFee] => 0
                                    [WireTransferFee] => 0
                                    [AppraisalFee] => 650
                                    [FloodCertification] => 0
                                    [CreditReport] => 35
                                    [OfferFeeOne] => 0
                                    [OfferDescOne] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [OfferFeeTwo] => 0
                                    [OfferDescTwo] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [OfferFeeThree] => 0
                                    [OfferDescThree] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [OtherFee] => 600
                                    [UpfrontMIPAmount] => 0
                                    [UpfrontMIorFundingFee] => 0
                                    [PriceStatus] => Active
                                    [Status] => Pass
                                    [StatusReason] => OK
                                    [LPPRIndex] => 10856759
                                    [PartnerId] => 0
                                    [PartnerName] => Save Financial
                                    [PartnerMessage] => n/a
                                    [PartnerOverageToCosts] => n/a
                                    [PartnerLicenseInfo] => n/a
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [LerId] => 599
                                    [LerName] => United Wholesale Mortgage
                                    [LerProductId] => 91823
                                    [LerProductName] => Conquest FreddieMac Elite 30 Year Fixed
                                    [LoanCategoryClass] => F360
                                    [LoanCategoryAmortization] => 30
                                    [LoanCategoryTerm] => 30
                                    [TargetMargin] => 100.899
                                    [LOComp] => 0.899
                                    [MaxEarningInPoints] => 9999999
                                    [MinEarningInPoints] => 0
                                    [PricesheetCompType] => 0
                                    [LerProductARMIndex] => 11
                                    [IndexName] => N/A
                                    [IndexValue] => 0
                                    [IndexDate] => 04/06/2008
                                    [IndexTime] => 02:48:02 PM
                                    [LerProductARMIndexMargin] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [LerProductARMLifeCap] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [LerProductARMFirstAdj] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [LerProductARMFirstAdjCap] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [LerProductARMPerAdj] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [LerProductARMPerAdjCap] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [LerProductProgram] => 0
                                    [LerProductFannieFreddie_SW] => 0
                                    [HomePath] => No
                                    [DURefi_HARP] => No
                                    [InterestOnly] => No
                                    [OpenAccess_HARP] => No
                                    [LerProductAllowPropertyLocationStandard] => 1
                                    [LerProductAllowPropertyLocationRural] => 1
                                    [LerProductLerPaidMI] => 0
                                    [SubPrime] => 0
                                    [Rate] =>   2.875
                                    [Points] => 101.307
                                    [Base] => 101.307
                                    [RateBase] => 101.307
                                    [Credit] => 1632
                                    [APR] => 2.900
                                    [MonthlyPayment] => 1659.57
                                    [MI] => 0.00
                                    [RateUp1] =>   2.998
                                    [PointsUp1] => 101.793
                                    [BaseUp1] => 101.307
                                    [RateBaseUp1] => 101.793
                                    [CreditUp1] => 3576
                                    [APRUp1] => 2.998
                                    [MonthlyPaymentUp1] => 1685.98
                                    [MIUp1] => 0.00
                                    [RateUp2] => 0
                                    [PointsUp2] => 0.000
                                    [BaseUp2] => 0.000
                                    [RateBaseUp2] => 0.000
                                    [CreditUp2] => 0
                                    [APRUp2] => 0
                                    [MonthlyPaymentUp2] => 0
                                    [MIUp2] => 0
                                    [RateUp3] => 0
                                    [PointsUp3] => 0.000
                                    [RateBaseUp3] => 0.000
                                    [BaseUp3] => 0.000
                                    [CreditUp3] => 0
                                    [APRUp3] => 0
                                    [MonthlyPaymentUp3] => 0
                                    [MIUp3] => 0
                                    [RateUp4] => 0
                                    [PointsUp4] => 0.000
                                    [RateBaseUp4] => 0.000
                                    [BaseUp4] => 0.000
                                    [CreditUp4] => 0
                                    [APRUp4] => 0
                                    [MonthlyPaymentUp4] => 0
                                    [MIUp4] => 0
                                    [RateUp5] => 0
                                    [PointsUp5] => 0.000
                                    [RateBaseUp5] => 0.000
                                    [BaseUp5] => 0.000
                                    [CreditUp5] => 0
                                    [APRUp5] => 0
                                    [MonthlyPaymentUp5] => 0
                                    [MIUp5] => 0
                                    [RateDown1] =>   2.750
                                    [PointsDown1] => 100.684
                                    [BaseDown1] => 101.307
                                    [RateBaseDown1] => 100.684
                                    [CreditDown1] => -860
                                    [APRDown1] => 2.824
                                    [MonthlyPaymentDown1] => 1632.96
                                    [MIDown1] => 0.00
                                    [RateDown2] =>   2.625
                                    [PointsDown2] => 99.922
                                    [BaseDown2] => 101.307
                                    [RateBaseDown2] => 99.922
                                    [CreditDown2] => -3908
                                    [APRDown2] => 2.758
                                    [MonthlyPaymentDown2] => 1606.60
                                    [MIDown2] => 0.00
                                    [RateDown3] =>   2.500
                                    [PointsDown3] => 99.083
                                    [BaseDown3] => 101.307
                                    [RateBaseDown3] => 99.083
                                    [CreditDown3] => -7264
                                    [APRDown3] => 2.698
                                    [MonthlyPaymentDown3] => 1580.48
                                    [MIDown3] => 0.00
                                    [RateDown4] => 0
                                    [PointsDown4] => 0.000
                                    [BaseDown4] => 0.000
                                    [RateBaseDown4] => 0.000
                                    [CreditDown4] => 0
                                    [APRDown4] => 0
                                    [MonthlyPaymentDown4] => 0
                                    [MIDown4] => 0
                                    [RateDown5] => 0
                                    [PointsDown5] => 0.000
                                    [BaseDown5] => 101.307
                                    [RateBaseDown5] => 0.000
                                    [CreditDown5] => 1632
                                    [APRDown5] => 0
                                    [MonthlyPaymentDown5] => 0
                                    [MIDown5] => 0
                                    [TotalAdjustments] => 0
                                    [BuydownPoints] => 0
                                    [DownPayment] => 200000
                                    [TotalFees] => 2940
                                    [APRFees] => 2940
                                    [POCFees] => 0
                                    [LerFees] => 2940
                                    [OriginationFees] => 0
                                    [ApplicationFee] => 150
                                    [ProcessingFee] => 1055
                                    [TaxFee] => 0
                                    [UnderWritingFee] => 0
                                    [DocumentFee] => 0
                                    [AdministrativeFee] => 450
                                    [CourierFee] => 0
                                    [WireTransferFee] => 0
                                    [AppraisalFee] => 650
                                    [FloodCertification] => 0
                                    [CreditReport] => 35
                                    [OfferFeeOne] => 0
                                    [OfferDescOne] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [OfferFeeTwo] => 0
                                    [OfferDescTwo] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [OfferFeeThree] => 0
                                    [OfferDescThree] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [OtherFee] => 600
                                    [UpfrontMIPAmount] => 0
                                    [UpfrontMIorFundingFee] => 0
                                    [PriceStatus] => Active
                                    [Status] => Pass
                                    [StatusReason] => OK
                                    [LPPRIndex] => 10856765
                                    [PartnerId] => 0
                                    [PartnerName] => Save Financial
                                    [PartnerMessage] => n/a
                                    [PartnerOverageToCosts] => n/a
                                    [PartnerLicenseInfo] => n/a
                                )
```

Comment: You wish to send $key['LerProductName'], $key['Rate'] & $key['APR'] to another page? Will the page always be the same url address?

Comment: no i wish to send the entire specific $key to another page. and yeah the page url is same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use get post method and encode the values using `base64_encode()` and then send them over the url... You will need the true keys however, so I changed the values you initially set as `key` to `value` and used the word `key` to get the actual keys for each value in the foreach loop.

I am using a variable to hold the data and then display it at the end of the php block, so you will not see any echo statements in the code.

PHP manual READ about $_GET: --> https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
PHP manual READ about base64_encode/base64_decode: --> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

---

**NOTE:** *I am unable to fully test this as I do not have access to the array you are using to construct your foreach loop, though I did test this using a dummy array and it worked without issue.*

---

Something like the following...

```php
<?php
$count = 1;
// $str will be the string that holds the key/value pairs that will be sent over the url
$str = '?'; //<-- ? starts the $_GET method for the url
foreach ($parser['LXEPricerGrid']['PassingLoans']['PassingLoan'] as $key => $value) {
      //<-- see if the $value is the last value we need, 
      //<-- if so, we remove the `&` and display only the key=value
      if($count === count($value)){
         //<-- concatenate the key/value pair to $str as the last value 
         $str .= $key.'='.base64_encode($value);
      }else{
         // concatenate the key/value and add `&` for the next iterations value to the $str
         $str .= $key.'='.base64_encode($value).'&';
      }
   // hold the table row in a variable for display later...
   $stmt = '
   <tr>

   <td>' . $count . '</td>
   <td>' . $value['LerProductName'] . '</td>
   <td>' . $value['Rate'] . '</td>
   <td>' . $value['APR'] . '</td>
   <td style="text-align: right">$' . $value['MonthlyPayment'] . '</td>
   <td><a href="#">Apply</a></td>
   <!-- since the url is the same no need for site url add the string to the href link for Details-->
   <td><a href="'.$str.'">Details</a></td>

   </tr>';
   $count++;

}
?>
<tbody>
    <!--// echo out the $stmt variable //-->
    <?=stmt?>
</tbody>
```

Then on the page you wish to send the array to, run a loop and reconstruct the array using the get values and the base64_decode()...

```php
//<-- declare empty array to hold data
$get = array();
if(!empty($_GET)){ //<-- if the $_GET global array is not empty... run the loop
    foreach($_GET as $index => $output){
        $get[$index] = base64_decode($output);
    }
}
var_dump($get); <--- $get now holds the decoded values
```

Comment: looks good the problem is that $value is actually an array so its giving me an error that base64 expects a string. Also if i dont encode i get an array to string conversion error. I'll post the array structure above

Comment: as you can see the $key is 0,1 and the $values are inside the 0 and 1.

Comment: also if i select the 5th row for example then its also sending all the previous values as well. i only need the $value for which is clicked on.

Comment: Thank you for your help but this answered worked for me :https://stackoverflow.com/a/14980062/7396313

Comment: How are you checking these values specifically? Are you using form? Push your checked value into a new array and then loop that to set your url string...

Comment: I see, careful sending unsecure data over the url though, you may want encode/decode it to secure it... Best